# Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql

Any ideas why the error `Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1'` occurs in this MySQL query?

```
UPDATE dossiers SET
attest_status = 'verstuurd'
WHERE `datum_dossier` = (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY > datum_dossier) AND attest != 'geen'
```

Field `datum_dossier` is set as `date` and has no values of `0000-00-00`.

I have another query that is working fine though:

```
UPDATE dossiers SET
reden_vervallen = 'Automatisch na 30 dagen',
datum_vervallen = NOW(),
status = 'vervallen'
WHERE soort = 'offerte' AND status = 'geoffereerd' AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY > datum_dossier)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down:

```
WHERE `datum_dossier` = (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY > datum_dossier)
```

This is a boolean comparison between `datum_dossier` (I assume this is a date) and the right-hand-side, which is itself a boolean expression:

```
(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY > datum_dossier)
```

This is a greater-than expression. It will not return a date, it will return a `1` (true) or `0` (false).

So you're trying to compare a date `datum_dossier` to a boolean value 1 or 0, which isn't a valid comparison:

```
WHERE `datum_dossier` = (1)
```

Whereas in your second query, it's just a series of boolean terms between `AND` operations:

```
WHERE soort = 'offerte' 
 AND status = 'geoffereerd' 
 AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY > datum_dossier)
```

You are not comparing any boolean to a date, so it's just fine.

Comment: Well, it is working in the second example. So why should it not be working on the first query?

Comment: The second example is a different query, and doesn't include an invalid comparison between a date and a boolean. I've edited my answer to try to clarify this.